# KafkaAvroDecoder object to DataFrame convertion

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, avro, confluent-schema-registry

In spark streaming with kafka and schema registry after receiving dstream how can I convert the dstream batch to Dataframe in spark?

Dstream type after using KafkaAvroDecoder from confluent is Dstream(String,Object). When I use below code it changes schema data type something like Int to Long in avro columns.

```
val kafkaStream: DStream[(String, Object)] =
      KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, Object, StringDecoder, KafkaAvroDecoder](
    ssc, kafkaParams, Set(topic)
      )

  // Load JSON strings into DataFrame
  kafkaStream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
    // Get the singleton instance of SQLContext
    val sqlContext = SQLContext.getOrCreate(rdd.sparkContext)
    import sqlContext.implicits._

val topicValueStrings = rdd.map(_._2.toString)
    val df = sqlContext.read.json(topicValueStrings)
```

[code reference](https://github.com/seanpquig/confluent-platform-spark-streaming/blob/master/src/main/scala/example/StreamingJob.scala)

Object.toSting and reading as json looses schema for int. Is there any other way instead of casting type in dataframe columns?